# How to install Ubuntu on a Chromebook?

Tags: installation, chromebook

I've just finished downloading Ubuntu for my C710 and rather than it being in Ubuntu it is still Chrome OS.

How do I install Ubuntu on a Chromebook?

Answer (score 0):

What Have you done after downloading the Ubuntu for your c710.

Maybe you have to make a bootable USB-Stick and boot from it and install ubuntu.
How to make a bootable USB-Stick: [How do you make USB bootable on chromebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278403/how-do-you-make-usb-bootable-on-chromebook)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343.

From the page:

> We're going to use a tool called Crouton to install Ubuntu (hat tip to
>   our friends at the How-To Geek), which uses the chroot command to run
>   Ubuntu on top of Chrome OS, which is already based on Linux. Unlike
>   dual-booting, that means you can switch between Chrome OS and Ubuntu
>   with a quick keyboard shortcut, no reboots necessary, which is
>   awesome. It's speedy, powerful, and there only when you need it. If
>   you prefer a more traditional dual-boot environment, check out
>   ChrUbuntu instead, but we'll be using Crouton today.

It can be done, and is only logical, as Chrome OS is based on Linux, like Ubuntu.

What it looks like your problem is you didn't set up dual-booting correctly, as Chromebooks work differently than regular computers for booting.

If you want to dual-boot, look here: http://liliputing.com/2012/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-on-the-199-acer-c7-chromebook.html. It gives instructions that are aimed at the Acer C7 using ChrUbuntu.

Should solve your problem relatively ASAP :D!

Best of Luck, will be following this.

BTW, if you get it working, could you post something within the post or something like a Community Wiki with what you did? That would probably be greatly appreciated in the community!