# Issues with bootable USB for ubuntu

Tags: usb

I followed instructions on this thread ([How do you make USB bootable on chromebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278403/how-do-you-make-usb-bootable-on-chromebook)) for making a bootable version of ubuntu on a USB drive, but it gets stuck at a certain point during booting ([http://m.imgur.com/RI77fL5](https://m.imgur.com/RI77fL5)).

I'm almost completely unexperienced so I have no idea how to proceed here. Any help is appreciated.