# need to load live image without shuting down

Tags: usb, live-usb, usb-drive

I have a Chromebook and want to boot a live image, but I can't find any applications that would allow me to do it.
I would like it to be preferably a small app.
Or maybe suggest a way to load your apps on a USB. That would be nice as well.
Any help would be nice.
I wouldn't mind a virtual machine but if it's not possible, I guess I'm out of luck and will consider alternative options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make USB bootable on chromebook](http://askubuntu.com/questions/278403/how-do-you-make-usb-bootable-on-chromebook)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like Ubuntu on your Chromebook, you should install [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton). It allows you to run Ubuntu, Debian, and Kali Linux in parallel with Chrome OS. You can do basic shell tasks and run a full desktop. I've used it, and it's very smooth.

If you need to boot a live image, you should look at [this other AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278403/how-do-you-make-usb-bootable-on-chromebook), which shows how to do that. You basically need to ensure the USB drive is made correctly and follow a set of instructions to boot off of it.

Comment: but when a ran sufo sh -e ~/Download/crouton -r kali -t xfce,xiwi it didnt work it said corrupted

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot to show me exactly what it says?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the virtual route, after initiating linux beta on your chromebook and upgrading and updating you could try:

> sudo apt-get install tasksel
>
> sudo tasksel

Follow the instructions for running tasksel

Then you'll need to find a way to access it. You could try:

> sudo apt install tightvncserver

When installing and first running the server you’ll be asked to set a password, do so.

To open the server after installation enter:

> vncserver

This will open the VNC graphical interface, and it will ask  you for your password, but also your IP address and port number.

To find your IP address enter in the terminal

> hostname -I

To find your port number enter in the terminal

> ss -tulw